# Ways of creating a Leave application form in Sharepoint?

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, custom-form

I need to create a form as part of the workflow with details and validation by taking some data from leave database such as Leave available and work replacement with other details.

So, i need to create form which reads data from a sql server database and validates input in in a format.

I know this can be done in two ways,

1. With Webpart in Visual Studio by fully coding
2. with Infopath by drag and drop, customization.

I want to know are there any other ways to do it, if there what it is ?

Are there any way to do it fully in Administrative mode i.e not so much coding, just doing customization and change some parameters, if that can you share any link of a tutorial of it.

I was trying with the Webpart in VS way, but couldn't finish it totally, are there any good tutorials available, i google a lot, but couldn't find the perfect one to meet my requirements. Please also share good materials on infopath on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**InfoPath Way:**
Have a look at [this](http://jamilhaddadin.com/2011/12/03/implementing-workflow-using-infopath-2010-and-sharepoint-designer-2010/), seems like he is showing what you want to achieve!

And if you want to learn more about InfoPath forms with SharePoint without any coding then you must follow [Laura Roger's Blog](http://www.sharepoint911.com/blogs/laura/Lists/Categories/Category.aspx?CategoryId=11&Name=InfoPath), she has written a book on [InfoPath with SharePoint](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735662061) as well

**Visual Web Pary Way**:
Visual Web Parts are just like you are using ASP.NET Application to build your custom solution [with a slight difference of [SharePoint Controls](http://karinebosch.wordpress.com/sharepoint-controls/) availability and SharePoint Object Model]... I would suggest you to read [SharePoint Object Model](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17215), and you will be doing Web Part development as a piece of cake :-)

**Another Way:**
You may create a custom list and modify its default form in SharePoint Designer to meet the custom validations and create a workflow on Custom List, again using OOB Workflows or custom Workflow in SharePoint Designer... But modifying list forms is quite a hectic, and is not preferred over InfoPath

**SUGGESTED**: Go for InfoPath Form, you will make your life easier!

I hope this helps